# C array pointer increment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indexing

Someone explain me this program. I've got a C code that makes use of pointer in array. For the below program

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    void function(char**);
    void main()
    {
        char *arr[] = {"ant","bat","cat","dog","egg","fly"};
        function(arr);
    }
    void function(char **ptr)
    {
        char *ptr1;
        ptr1 = (ptr+=sizeof(int))[-2];
        printf("%s\n",ptr1); 
    }
```

I'm getting the output as `cat` when using the index -2. Starting from the right corner the index value begins from 1. How does this happen. How does the index value behave this way rather than starting its index position from 0 from the left side. I expected the below values to be in the array

```
index value
0   ant
1   bat
2   cat
3   dog
4   egg
5   fly
```

But what the output was is

```
index value
-4  ant
-3  bat
-2  cat
-1  dog
0   egg
1   fly
```

How does this work?

Comment: What do you expect from `ptr+=sizeof(int)`?

Comment: It seems `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your system.

Comment: Your out put does not match the code you posted. Also your code is nonsensical

Comment: Using an online compiler my  `ptr1 = *(ptr+=sizeof(int))` points to `egg`, so [-2] steps you back 2 from there to get  `cat`. So it seems your system is doing the same as tutorialspoints onine compiler.

Comment: This question was asked from "Zoho corp" Interview. So i just wanna undersand this and know how this works exactly.

Comment: I wanna know what does "ptr1 = (ptr+=sizeof(int))" (11th line) this contain?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you have some issues with your program but i'll try my best...

first, your issue lies with th line `ptr1 = (ptr+=sizeof(int))[-2];` I can't understand what you expect it will do but what it actually does is `ptr = ptr[4]; ptr1 = ptr[-2]`

I tried to put out some debugging info to be more clear on the matter,

strings mapped in memory

```
0x400624 ant
0x400628 bat
0x40062c cat
0x400630 dog
0x400634 egg
0x400638 fly
```

to verify `sizeof(int)` is 4

at the start of `function`

```
*ptr - 0x400624 - "ant"
```

after your assignment to `ptr1`

```
*ptr - 0x400634 - "egg"
ptr1 = 0x40062c - "cat"
```

as you can see

1. `ptr` now points to "egg" as the actual assignment to it was `ptr = ptr[4]`
2. ptr1 is now pointing to "cat" as it is assigned `ptr1 = ptr[-2]`

You should readup on two things: "C order of evaluation" and also "pointer arithmatics"

Hope this helps...